# Google Sheets - Ignore empty cells (JOIN & QUERY)

Tags: google-sheets

I'm pretty new to googlesheets and I have a set of data that will update based on input from others and I wanted to filter data based on two matched values.

```
=JOIN(", ",QUERY('Form responses 1'!$D$2:$E,"SELECT D WHERE E = '"&$A$2:$A&"'"))
```

I have this formula and this works for my needs however it also returns a bunch of commas when there are numerous blank cells. What can I do to get it to the ignore blank cells?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992) with the second parameter (ignore_empty) `TRUE`

Syntax:
`TEXTJOIN(delimiter, ignore_empty, text1, [text2, ...])`

Sample Usage:

```
TEXTJOIN(“ “, TRUE, “hello”, “world”)
TEXTJOIN(“, ”, FALSE, A1:A5)
```